# C++ Win32 Schedule Task Fails because of bad XML

Tags: c++, winapi, scheduled-tasks

I am fiddling with the Windows Task Scheduler & attempting to schedule a task to execute when I log in.

**So I have copied & pasted the exact example code from MSDN on how to do this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911(v=VS.85).aspx - I have specified my user name & my password in the code example. When I run it I get the error "Failed to save task: 80041318"**

Thanks to people in another question I made I now know this error means:

> The task XML contains a value which is incorrectly formatted or out of range

Now I dont know what this means, what am I doing incorrectly in my code, especially when 99% is a direct copy of the example MSDN code?

**Maybe I need to format my username & password correctly because they are BSTR or VARIANT's?**

I will post only the changes I made to the code but to see the whole code go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381911(v=VS.85).aspx:

```
hr = pLogonTrigger->put_UserId( _bstr_t( L"soribo" ) );  // soribo is my username
pLogonTrigger->Release();                                // line 221

hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(  // line 289
        _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
        pTask,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 
        _variant_t(L"soribo"), // put in my windows username again (I'm the admin)
        _variant_t(L"XXXXXX"), // put in my user password & no its not really XXXXXX :P 
        TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTask);
```

I dont understand where XML comes in because this is C++ Win32 code?

**EDIT: Showing pTask related code**: note I didn't change any of this, so its the example code from MSDN

```
//  Create the task builder object to create the task.
ITaskDefinition *pTask = NULL;
hr = pService->NewTask( 0, &pTask );

pService->Release();  // COM clean up.  Pointer is no longer used.
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    printf("Failed to create a task definition: %x", hr);
    pRootFolder->Release();
    CoUninitialize();
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: The XML is in the pTask properties.  Can you show how you initialize pTask?

Comment: @John: See the edits in the question for pTask init

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the cause of your error, but looking at the documentation of [ITaskFolder::RegisterTaskDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381365%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and your code:

```
hr = pRootFolder->RegisterTaskDefinition(  // line 289
        _bstr_t( wszTaskName ),
        pTask,
        TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, 
        _variant_t(L"soribo"), // put in my windows username again (I'm the admin)
        _variant_t(L"XXXXXX"), // put in my user password & no its not really XXXXXX :P 
        TASK_LOGON_GROUP,
        _variant_t(L""),
        &pRegisteredTask);
```

I see you are using TASK_LOGON_GROUP, but pass an username password. If you use TASK_LOGON_GROUP, you should probably use a name of a group (like `L"Builtin\\Administrators"` or [`L"S-1-5-32-545"`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/243330)) and VT_NULL for the password.